# Python: Reading Ftp file list with UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, ftp, ftplib

Hi I am using module ftplib. And list my files with this code:

```
files=[]
files = ftp.nlst()
```

And write them to text file with this code:

```
for item in files:
    filenames.write(item +'\n')
```

But there is an encoding problem that if my file name has 'ı,ğ,ş' characters, It cant read this and writes to file with '?' instead.

How can read them properly?

Comment: could you copy the Exception it is rising ?

Comment: related: [Confirm that Python 2.6 ftplib does not support Unicode file names? Alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120295/confirm-that-python-2-6-ftplib-does-not-support-unicode-file-names-alternatives)

Answer (score 15):

Python 3.x is using default encoding ISO-8859-1 for file name.

To use UTF-8 encoding for file name with the server, you need to add the following line:

```
ftpConnector = ftplib.FTP(host,user,password) # connection

ftpConnector.encoding='utf-8' #force encoding for file name in utf-8 rather than default that is iso-8889-1
```

then you can use:

```
ftpConnector.storbinary( 'STOR '+fileName, file) # filename will be utf-8 encoded
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. Tested with python 3  and filezilla server

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the resulting items back to unicode before writing the items to file. The ftp module does not support unicode strings. To do this try:

```
import encodings.idna

for item in files:
    filenames.write(encodings.idna.ToUnicode(item) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried your solution but I got "<class 'UnicodeError'>" exception.

Comment: Can you give more details please? If you rerun, paste the entire error message here please.

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp.encoding='utf-8'
ftp.sendcmd('OPTS UTF8 ON')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.9 ([bpo-39380](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18048)) the *default encoding* of `ftplib.FTP` has been set to `utf-8`, and the FTP constructor offers an `encoding` parameter.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(..., encoding='utf-8')
```

However this change is probably an incompatible and bogus solution, broke a lot of existing code, and the `nlst` commands etc. since that break with `UnicodeDecodeError` as soon as random files on a server have names with do not do have proper utf-8 encoding.
(You can't robustly read / inspect an unknown directory safely with the new default. And `OPTS UTF8 ON` FTP command has not been established and is usually a no-op on unix servers with 8bit file names - it effectively only allows 8bit transfer instead of 7bit ASCII for commands, which happens / happened as well without the command.).

The formerly fixed `latin-1` encoding attribute of `FTP`, which is applied to the whole command traffic, not just filenames, was probably never meant to be a *default encoding*. No RFC or so ever recommended / preferred `latin-1`. But to enable an unrestricted 8-bit API for the 8-bit FTP protocol - though on PY3 with 8bit pseudo strings in the form of normal comfortable (unicode) strings using the lowest 256 chars.

For robust FTP its currently necessary to switch the internal encoding of ftplib.FTP back (in Py3.9+) to latin-1 / pseudo 8bit strings, do inspections maybe on the pseudo 8bit strings, and do the (optionally error-tolerant) encoding / decoding outside like this:

```
ftp.encoding = 'latin-1'   # or ftp = FTP(..., encoding='latin-1')
...
fn_ftp_utf8 = fn.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
...
fn = fn_ftp_utf8.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')
```

In future there may be / should be at least an `errors` parameter for `ftplib.FTP` in addition to the `encoding` parameter in order to allow simple use cases for the *automatic encoding mode*.